# parent links depends on window.print() on target="_blank"

Tags: google-chrome, printing

I have a page, that open another page with target="_blank" and on this page I have a window. print () in onLoad. So, it opens a print dialog and I can't go in other links on the parent page. If I close print dialog it works fine, and if I use ctrl+p to open print dialog it's ok too. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to be able to click other links in the parent page when the print dialog is open? Is that the question?

Comment: right, I want to click other links in parent

Comment: It would not be possible since the print dialog is a model dialog in general. However if you are using chrome then chrome print dialog should open and you should be able to navigate to parent tab/window and click links, since chrome print dialog is not model. Show some screenshots here to know whats happening.

Comment: It simple. I use chrome. Children and parent pages are opened. Going to children page, write in console window.print() and print dialog is open, then going to parent page and click on link, page start downloading and nothing happens. Going to children where print dialog is opened pressing cancel button and parent going to link what was pressed. As I say before, if I use ctrl+p to open print dialog all is ok. You can see this on any site, edit link with html editor - add target="_blank" click on it, write in console window.print(), go on previous page and click another link.

Comment: It is known issue in Chrome v34 and v35 - https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=359627